# Question about python math.ceil() and math.floor()

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
num = math.log(536870912) / math.log(2)  # num = 29.0
ceil = math.ceil(num)
floor = math.floor(num)
print(ceil, floor)
```

The output is (30.0, 29.0)

My question is when I just print math.ceil(29.0) the result is 29.0, why the above code gives me the 30.0 as ceiling?

Comment: Floats are approximations and `num` might be a tiny bit off from 29.0

Comment: Because [floating point math is inaccurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) (which is as necessary as "our" decimal system is inherently flawed as well – you can't even write down an accurate decimal version of `1/3`!).

Comment: if you print your num, you will see it's slightly above 29.0 (29.000000000000004)

Comment: Note that there's also [`math.log2`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log2), which tends to be more accurate than the division version you have. You may also want to look into [`int.bit_length`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length).

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the inaccuracies of [floating point math in python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/floating-point-error-in-python/#:~:text=This%20can%20be%20considered%20as,Python%2C%20but%20it%20is%20not.&text=It's%20a%20problem%20caused%20when,to%20represent%20a%20decimal%20number.).

Print the number too:

```py
import math
num = math.log(536870912) / math.log(2)  # num = 29.0 (not actually)
ceil = math.ceil(num)
floor = math.floor(num)
print(num, ceil, floor)
```

```py
29.000000000000004 30 29
```

[`ceil()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_ceil.htm) will return the the next highest integer.

I suggest using [`round()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_round.asp)

Comment: Very good, but a more relevant link would be to [Python's official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html), which discusses this as well.

Comment: Agreed official is best - Although sometimes the oficial documentation can be daunting for new users - It is a good habit to get into

Answer (score 1):

Because num does not equal to 29.0 exactly. 
If you print it, you will get something like 29.000000000000004:

```
import math
num = math.log(536870912) / math.log(2)  # num = 29.0
print(num)
ceil = math.ceil(num)
floor = math.floor(num)
print(ceil, floor)
```

Output:

```
29.000000000000004
30 29
```

You can check out this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I could say because

`math.log(536870912) / math.log(2) = 29.000000000000004`

And

`29.000000000000004 != 29.0`

As usr2564301 points out, [floating point math is inaccurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).